# What's wrong with the angle trisection using Intercept theorem?

Tags: angle

Could anyone tell what I'm missing?

I know that angle trisection is proven to be impossible (see Pierre Wantzel in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection).
However, I just came up with the following method and can't find any flaw

Steps (sorry, I'm not super precise describing it)

1. Given angle ABC
2. draw a circle from point B, to intersect both angle lines in U and L points
3. join created points to get line segment UL
4. multiply the segment 3 (since it's trisection) times on one of angle line (creating points L1, L2, L3 or U1, U2, U3 depends on which line you pick)
5. draw a line crossing L3 & U points (or U3 & L)
6. draw a parallel line that crosses L2 and UL in point X1
7. draw a parallel line that crosses L2 and UL in point X2
8. draw one line crossing points B & X1
9. draw one line crossing points B & X2

Now the angle ABC should be divided into 3 equal angles?

You can also watch quick presentation/draft with computer program.

https://odysee.com/@xliiv:f/trisect-angle-with-tales:2

Perhaps, here's the reason why the method is false, but can't catch it
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem#Algebraic_formulation_of_compass_and_ruler_constructions

Comment: It looks like you are trisecting a chord. Note that to trisect the angle, you should really trisect the arc of the circle instead.

Comment: @xliiv NDB is correct. The reason your trisection doesn't work is because the relationship between a chord and its corresponding arc is not a linear one.

Comment: NDB, H.sapiensrex  you're right. Now i understand the reason and difference, so you have answered my question. Thank you!